# Sending all dynamic states to JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS to let my users dynamically generate a form and then save that form data. So, for example, they can have a form with 3 elements (a textarea, select field, and text field). They title it whatever they want and input values. Those field titles and values are saved dynamically as states using

```
setState({ [name]: value}).
```

This works fine. Now I want to convert all of those states to JSON and send via Ajax. However, I don't know what the user has titled those states, so I tried doing the following:

```
JSON.stringify({
    "data": this.state
})
```

However, this throws the error 'Converting circular structure to JSON', I'm guessing because this.state also includes Object data.

Is there any way for me to send all states via Ajax without actually knowing what all the states are named?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the state even not knowing the names with Object.keys()

```
Object.keys(this.state).map((name) => {
   console.log(this.state[name]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On form submit create form object using `FormData` for your form and that will post all the values within form like below

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    // Assuming you are using fetch
    fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried multiple ways to get the FormData by the event.target. I even tried adding a ref to the form itself, but it didn't work. Not sure why.